# AmCharts v5, how to show tooltip text on MapPolygon series according to conditions?

Tags: amcharts5

I am working with MapPolygon of AmCharts v5. And according to a real word condition that the `value can be 0`, I want to set condition on its series that if the value equals 0, makes it disables `tooltip`.

I have been trying to google it and tried many possible ways, but to no avail I can't solve it.

This is one of the possible code I've tried, thinking it would work.

```
var polygonSeries = map.series.push(am5map.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, {
    geoJSON: myMap,
    valueField : "value",
    calculateAggregates: true
    })
);

polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
    strokeWidth: 1.25,
    tooltipText: "[bold]{name}[/]: {value}s",
    fill:am5.color(0xaaaaaa),
    fillOpacity: 1
});

polygonSeries.tooltip.set("disabled", function({target}) {
    if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.get("valueY") === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

There seems to be a problem with `set("disabled")`. Please help correct this code

Answer (score 0):

After trying and testing, I finally found the right solution to the above question. So I am here again to share the solution code.

Instead of using,

> polygonSeries.tooltip.set("disabled", function({target}) { ... });

which is not right, I use the below code to set on an `event` called `pointover`.

```
polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.events.on("pointerover", function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.dataItem.get("value") === undefined) {
        polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
            tooltipText: ""
        });
    } else {
        polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
            tooltipText: "[bold]{name}[/]: {value} s"
        });
    }
});
```

This might not be the best practice of code, but it works.

Thanks. Have a nice day coding!!